# Laravel on Docker [2002] Connection refused to Mysql on Port 3307

Tags: mysql, docker, laravel-5, docker-compose, port

Got a Laravel 5.8 application spun up locally on Docker.

I can run the app on my browser, connect to the database on Sequel Pro, but when I try and migrate the database, I get the dreaded `[2002] Connection refused` error.

I have set the mysql port to 3307 as I have another mysql container using 3306 for a different project.  I don't want to have to keep stopping and starting docker for each project as I might be flicking between the 2 regularly, that's why I'm using different ports.

Here is the mysql section in the docker-compose file.

```
mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: 127.0.0.1
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_DATABASE: forecast
      MYSQL_USER: forecast
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
    volumes:
      - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - forecast
```

Here is my .env file DB set up keys

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3307
DB_DATABASE=forecast
DB_USERNAME=forecast
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Also worth noting I am running the app on port 81, instead of 80 for the same reason.  In my browser, I have to put `{domain.testing}:81` which works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have figured this out for anyone having the same problem.

I had to adjust my .env file.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

So I changed the `DB_HOST` to `mysql` and the `DB_PORT` back to `3306` as docker maps it to 3307.  Then it worked successfully.

Answer (score 1):

change `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1` to `DB_HOST=mysql` and it should work. Because in container network your host is **mysql** not 127.0.0.1.

And also because of port forwarding there is no need to change .env 3306 to 3307. docker will do based on network settings. Leave it as `DB_PORT=3306`

Answer (score 0):

Change `127.0.0.1` to `mysql`

```
mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: mysql
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_DATABASE: forecast
      MYSQL_USER: forecast
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
    volumes:
      - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - forecast
```